# In java, how can a deeply immutable objects contains instances of classes that are not immutable?

Tags: java

I do not very understand this statement, is this sentence means that there can be a mutable nested class in an immutable object(class)? Any examples for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible for an immutable type to be composed from mutable types - so long as:

- They make sure they don't accept references to mutable objects externally without cloning them
- They never mutate the objects themselves (at least not in a visible way)
- They never return a reference to a mutable object to callers

Here's an example:

```java
import java.util.Date;

public final class Person {
    private final String name;
    // Note: I don't recommend using Date generally, but
    // it's a convenient type to use as an example.
    private final Date registrationTimestamp;

    public Person(String name, Date registrationTimestamp) {
        this.name = name;
        this.registrationTimestamp = new Date(registrationTimestamp.getTime());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Date getRegistrationTimestamp() {
        return new Date(registrationTimestamp.getTime());
    }
}
```

It's clunky because of the cloning of `Date` - which demonstrates that it's *better* to compose immutable types from other immutable types where possible (and it's definitely better to use `java.time` types over `java.util.Date`!) but that it's *possible* to make a type immutable even if it uses mutable types internally.